# Java Mail Class

Tags: java, email

I am looking for a Java class that will allow me to send emails without the need for SMTP. Like the PHP mail() class that uses sendmail.

Any suggestions?

Many Thanks

James

Comment: What makes you think that sendmail doesn't use SMTP?

Comment: Well where does sendmail connect to then if it does?

Comment: this works http://examples.oreilly.com/jenut/SendMail.java

Comment: @James Moore, it uses the `mail.host` property which is an address to a SMTP server.

Comment: Indeed, you've got some misconception here. In PHP the SMTP server is configured in `php.ini`.

Comment: so looking at php it uses /sendomain -t to send emails, soo how does sendmail work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

http://examples.oreilly.com/jenut/SendMail.java

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Before Using this Program, you need to have Javasoft's JavaMail class files which can be downloaded from here http://www.javasoft.com/products/javamail/index.html

You will also need the JavaBeansTM Activation Framework extension or JAF (javax.activation). It is available at http://java.sun.com/beans/glasgow/jaf.html.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;
public void postMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from) throws MessagingException
{
    boolean debug = false;

     //Set the host smtp address
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.jcom.net");

    // create some properties and get the default Session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    // create a message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // set the from and to address
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
    {
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
    }
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);


    // Optional : You can also set your custom headers in the Email if you Want
    msg.addHeader("MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue");

    // Setting the Subject and Content Type
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All mail senders will need an SMTP server to transfer their mail. The nice thing about PHP mail is that you don’t need to configure it (it use the *sendmail* binary directly, if *sendmail* is not installed, PHP mail will not work either).

If all you want is building a Java application that can send out e-mail without configuring an SMTP server for that, you could use a Java based SMTP server, for example:

**[Apache James](http://james.apache.org/)**